# How can we add case details and filtering to the CiviCRM dashboard?

Tags: civicase, dashboard

In future CiviCRM versions would it be possible to added extra functionality to the civi case dashboard, specifically allowing the dashboard to use filters to display the data, e.g. order by contact name alphabetically.

Comment: Your question is unclear, are you asking for a new feature or are you asking if it's possible to do something

Comment: Also the subject for this question is really unhelpful as it could refer to anything when you are specifically asking about civicase.

Answer (score 5):

It's opensource, whatever you want today you can change... provided you implement the change you want.

As for future versions... well, the future isn't written, so if you are willing to code or fund the changes you want, the answer is "yes", to whatever you make happen.

Comment: @user2636 You could get the ball rolling by submitting a feature request to the issue queue, particularly if it is a feature you would be able to fund =]